# How to setup Test Users to submit my App using "Instagram Public Content Access" features?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram-graph-api

My problem is: how to submit my App to Facebook Review with Test Users in order to allow the Facebook Reviewer to see that it works with the "Instagram Public Content Access" feature?

Now, to detail my problem.

During the development phase of my app, I used an Test App (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-apps/) and Test Users (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users/) to access the "Hashtag Search API" (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/hashtag-search/, which requires the "Instagram Public Content Access" feature - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#reference-INSTAGRAM_PUBLIC_CONTENT_ACCESS). That worked fine: I have Test Users on the Test App that can use my it the same way as my final users will do.

Now I'm trying to submit my "Production" App to Facebook Review in order to get the "Instagram Public Content Access". If I submit the Production app to Facebook Review, I can't select any of the Test Users from the Test App on the submission form (I can only select Test Users from the Production App). If I create Test Users on the Production App, these can't use the feature (I receive errors saying that I need to pass it through the App Review first). And if I don't provide an Test User on the submission form, the Facebook Reviewer will be unable to test my App, and probably will reject the feature request.

So, how do I setup my App Review submission in order to allow the Facebook Reviewer to test and authorize my Production App? I need to submit the Production App but my functionality only works with the Test App.

Comment: The reviewers have accounts available to test apps, that are not restricted by such limitations. Unless it explicitly says anywhere that you need to provide a test user, or you have a scenario that can only be tested with a particular test user setup you created, you don’t normally need to provide test users.

Comment: Thanks @04FS! So do you think that the screencast describing what data is needed on the test user is enough to allow the reviewer to check how my app uses the features?

Comment: What specific data is needed, does your app have any specific requirements? For a general hashtag search on public pages(?) I would assume you’d be able to test that with almost anything, and see appropriate results within the app?

Comment: Thanks @04FS, I will try to submit it without test users :)

Comment: @igfischer or anyone... How did you add the Instagram Public Content Access feature to your test app or test users, I'm stumped here?